# How to properly align columns in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, mac-os-x

I recently began learning with SQLite, and I am trying to output the data of a table into the Terminal (macOS). However, the result after I've set `.mode column` or `.mode tab` is not properly aligned when some columns have no data, such in the second entry.

For example, in column mode where Donna doesn't have age and place data:

```
name            surname             age         place              
--------------  ------------------  ----------  ------------------
John  Smith  34          assistant manager
Donna  Patterson
```

and in tab mode:

```
name surname  age   place   
John Smithonian     34 assistant manager
Donna Patterson
```

but the desirable result is:

```
name            surname             age         place              
--------------  ------------------  ----------  ------------------
John            Smith               34          assistant manager
Donna           Patterson
```

Is there anything I am not aware of? All the examples in the book I study from depict all columns properly aligned.

The same thing happens with tab mode.

*I am working through Terminal.app on a mac with the pre-installed 3.8 version of SQLite*

In later tests, I discovered that if my columns are all filled with information, it is possible to have all data aligned or not. It depends on the information. When I added a `Phone Number` column to one of the examples, the nice arrangement was lost.

Comment: Since the empty spaces (NULL values) seem to be the problem, have you tried to change the way they are displayed instead of an empty space? `.nullvalue [NULL]` for example.

Comment: @Matjaž Perhaps this is the answer. Could you please provide an answer and explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `.mode tab` the output is not guaranteed to be aligned because af the nature of the TAB characters. On the other hand `.mode column` should be working fine.

Since it looks like empty fields for NULL values are creating problems, you can change the way NULL values are displayed with `.nullvalue SOMESTRING`. I personally like `.nullvalue [NULL]`.

Summing it up:

```
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .nullvalue [NULL]
sqlite> SELECT * FROM people;
name            surname             age         place              
--------------  ------------------  ----------  ------------------
John            Smith               34          assistant manager
Donna           Patterson           [NULL]      [NULL]
```

Also be sure to check the `.width` option to set the number of characters per column (negative values to right-align, 0 to reset) in case you need it.

Comment: took me three years, but I finaly made it, to award your answer. ;)

Comment: Appreciated! :)

Comment: These commands can be added to ~/.sqliterc to make them persistent.  Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240643/change-sqlite-default-settings (the second result in the search that brought me here).